# Trigger another jenkins job execute shell

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How to trigger a jenkins job from another freestyle job execute shell section? For pipeline jobs we have groovy which makes it easy.

Answer (score 0):

[image: freesstyle]

Two ways to do.

1 - Add a post-build step to build another project

2 - Create a user in jenkins to build remotely jobs (example remoteUser). Create a API TOken for this user. Edit the project to be triggered and make the option “Trigger Builds Remotely”, add an authentication token (IT'S NOT THE TOKEN OF THE USER, YOU CAN GENERATE A NEW FOR THIS). 
 Now can just use curl to start the job

```
curl -X POST HTTP://remoteUser:{remoteUser_API_TOKEN}@jenkins.domain/project/my_project/build?token=TOKEN
```